Is "parallel composition hierarchies" a code smell?
For example, suppose I have a mobile app that uses some user data, the DTO:
class UserData{
public:
  Address address;
  bool isVerified=false;
};

class Address{
};

The UserData may be loaded from the server JSON, so I need rapidJson, and also write some methods to assign the data from rapidJson to the object.
Instead of using active record pattern :
class UserData{
public:
  Address address;
  bool isVerified=false;

  void jsonToObj(rapidJson::Value& value){
    this->address.jsonToObj(value);
    this->isVerified=value["isVerified"].GetBool();
  }
};

class OldPlayerResumeGameScene : public GameScene{
public:
  onLoad(){
    rapidJson::Value value = (some methods that process JSON string from http response);
    UserData::getInstance().jsonToObj(value);
  }
} 

that writes the json-to-object methods to the object itself, I create some parallel serializer classes that resembles the structure of UserData:
class UserDataSerializer{
public:
  static void jsonToObj(rapidJson::Value& value,UserData& userData){
      AddressSerializer::jsonToObj(value["address"],userData.address);

      userData.isVerified=value["isVerified"].GetBool();
  }
};

class AddressSerializer{
  static void jsonToObj(rapidJson::Value& value,Address& address){
  }
};

So that only the pages that loads UserData depend on the UserDataSerializer class:
class OldPlayerResumeGameScene : public GameScene{
public:
  onLoad(){
    rapidJson::Value value = (some methods that process JSON string from http response);
    UserDataSerializer::jsonToObj(value,UserData::getInstance());
  }
} 

while other pages that don't need to load UserData from JSON string would depend on UserData class only instead of UserDataSerializer class, for example:
class ShowUserInfoScene : public GameScene{
public:
  onLoad(){
    Label* countryLabel=UserData::getInstance().address.country;
    .
    .
    .
  }
}

When UserData adds a new object property, I also need a new serializer, for example, when I add a new property DateOfBirth:
class UserData{
public:
  Address address;
  bool isVerified=false;
  DateOfBirth dateOfBirth;
};

, I would also add a DateOfBirthSerializer class:
class DateOfBirthSerializer{
pulbic:
  static void jsonToObj(rapidJson::Value& value,DateOfBirth& dateOfBirth){
  }
}

and also update UserDataSerializer class in parallel:
class UserDataSerializer{
public:
  static void jsonToObj(rapidJson::Value& value,UserData& userData){
      AddressSerializer::jsonToObj(value["address"],userData.address);

      userData.isVerified=value["isVerified"].GetBool();

      DateOfBirthSerializer::jsonToObj(value["dateOfBirth"],userData.dateOfBirth);
  }
};

My question is, is create ???Serializer class in parallel as above a code smell?

The question is missing sufficient context to rule on this. If those two classes represent two separate responsibilities each with their own life cycles, then they both have a purpose. If not, then not.

Totally irrelevant but you have a couple of funny typos in your code snippets.

A large part of this looks like the inevitable consequence of trying to apply Java/C# style serialisation in C++.     Serialisation in C++ has traditionally been a somewhat 'ugly' topic compared with other languages, although things have improved - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549906/c-json-serialization
